# Showing high res images makes my app crash in my react-native app, How can I solve this?

Tags: react-native

I need to show about 20 high res images in my view with scroll, so when I run my app during the scroll my app will crash in my iphone 6 plus. I checked xcode and find this error message:

[process_info] Exiting because our workspace host has disconnected.
XPC connection interrupted

I had a flat list with lots of imageSlides in it, which each one of them is a 'JourneySlide' component.

here is my code :

```
export class JourneySlide extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      refreshCount : 0,
    }
  }

  constructViews = () => {
    let slideMissions = []; 
    this.props.levels.forEach((item , index)=> {           
      slideMissions.push(
        <JourneyMission 
        maxLvlNumber={this.props.levels[0].level_number}
        seasonID={this.props.season_id}
        is_locked={item.is_locked}
        is_completed={item.is_completed}
        prize_value={item.prize_value}
        prize_type={item.prize_type}
        level_number={item.level_number}
        message=""
        level_id={item.level_id}
        onPress={this.props.onPress}
        itemIndex={index}
        asset_height={this.props.asset_height}
        asset_width={this.props.asset_width}
        pos_Y={item.pos_Y}      
        pos_x={item.pos_x}      
        />
      )        
    })
    return slideMissions;
  }

  render() {
    console.log('Journey Slide render again')
    let sizeH = normalize(42);
    let {  
      asset_height,
      asset_width,
      asset_name,
      title,
      sub_title,                  
    } = this.props; 
        let slideHeight = checkHeight(asset_width,asset_height)
      return (
        <View style={[{height: slideHeight, width : widthx}]}>
          {/* {this.constructViews()} */}
          <FlatList 
            data={this.props.levels}
            keyExtractor={(item) => item.level_id }
            renderItem={({item, index}) => 
            <JourneyMission 
            maxLvlNumber={this.props.levels[0].level_number}
            seasonID={this.props.season_id}
            is_locked={item.is_locked}
            is_completed={item.is_completed}
            prize_value={item.prize_value}
            prize_type={item.prize_type}
            level_number={item.level_number}
            message=""
            level_id={item.level_id}
            onPress={this.props.onPress}
            itemIndex={index}
            asset_height={this.props.asset_height}
            asset_width={this.props.asset_width}
            pos_Y={item.pos_Y}      
            pos_x={item.pos_x}      
            />}            
            showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
            style={{zIndex:2}}
            getItemLayout={(data, index) => (
              {length: sizeH, offset: sizeH * index, index}
            )}
          />
         <Image 
         style={{
           position: 'absolute',
           zIndex: 1,          
           width: widthx,
           height: slideHeight
         }}
         // resizeMode="stretch"
         resizeMethod="resize"
         source={journey[asset_name]}
        /> 
        </View> 
      );    
  }
}
```

this is where I add each images to my view witch they usually have 2048*2732 and above res

```
<Image 
         style={{
           position: 'absolute',
           zIndex: 1,          
           width: widthx,
           height: slideHeight
         }}
         // resizeMode="stretch"
         resizeMethod="resize"
         source={journey[asset_name]}
        />
```

So my problem is the crash issue during the scrolling, I also checked memory use during scroll, it's about 200 mb and 20% cpu usage during scroll.

I checked this app on newer iphone and it works fine but I need to handle this issue on iphone 6 and 5s
please help me with your advices.

Comment: Maybe try some list virtualization/windowing, or pagination on these older devices that maybe can't handle rendering the entire list of images.

Comment: I'm already using a Flatlist in my parent component to list these images and also to prevent rendering all images. but after some scrolling and changing view go and back it will crash.

Answer (score 2):

Two suspicious:

(1) I would take a look at ([flatlist-performance-tips](https://github.com/filipemerker/flatlist-performance-tips)) for general tips, but in particular look at `windowSize`. Flatlist will continue rendering a "buffer" of items that are offscreen. In your case, the default values of Flatlist are causing your list to render all your images all the time, once you've scrolled far enough down. Since your images are large, this may be your issue.

(2) How often are your Flatlist items updating? You may not be changing the props/state of the component, but the component may still be doing quite a bit of processing. When I render a static list, I usually extend Purecomponent and then return false on `shouldComponentUpdate`. This is a huge performance boost in general.

Comment: About your first suggestion, my images sholud be full screen so I calculate image width and height based of windows width, and also I used initialNumToRender={2} in my Flatlist, because basically two images will cover my whole screen so I set it to 2.
And about your second suggestion I'm already doing exactly as you mentioned and prevent extra rendering, but it seems Images high res is the main problem.

Comment: Even with initialNumToRender={2} once you scroll down the FlatList is still rendering an extra 10 - 20 by default. Try setting windowSize={1}